# Paypal subscription auto payments on a specific day?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am offering an annual program and want to automatically withdraw payments from my clients via PayPal. I see how to create a subscription to do this.

However, it charges them one month after they pay the first installment. I really want to bill all of my clients on the 1st of the month for 12 months, to simply the accounting for myself and them.

Is there a way to create an automatic payment on the 1st of every month without asking all of my clients to pay on that specific day?

I called Paypal and they said it would require html coding, but couldn't tell me HOW that might be accomplished for someone like me who doesn't write code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Recurring Payments API you can specify the PROFILESTARTDATE and set it to whatever future date you want.  The profile will be become active immediatly, but it won't start until that date, which is when the first payment would be made.

Just keep in mind if somebody signs up on the 2nd of the month you'll basically be giving them a free month.